# Передача объекта с сервера клиенту http

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

```
 private CrmDbEntities db = new CrmDbEntities();

    // GET: api/Dealings
    //получение списка сделок

    public WorkspaceData Get()       
    {
        WorkspaceData workspaceData = new WorkspaceData();

        ObservableCollection<IDealing> dealings = new ObservableCollection<IDealing>(); 
        IEnumerable<DealingsStage> dealingsStages = new List<DealingsStage>();
        ObservableCollection<Client> clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();

        var _dealings = db.Dealings;
        var _clients = db.Clients;
        dealingsStages = db.DealingsStages;

        //сколько сделок, столько и клиентов. На каждую сделку по клиенту
        foreach (var d in _dealings)
        {
            DealingData dealing = new DealingData(d);
            //IClient client = new Client(_clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientId == d.ClientId));
            Client cl = _clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientId == d.ClientId);

            //Client client = new Client();
            clients.Add(cl);
            dealings.Add(dealing);
        }

        workspaceData.DealingsStage = dealingsStages;
        workspaceData.DealingData = dealings;
        workspaceData.ClientData = clients;

        return workspaceData;
    }
```

Есть контроллер, унаследованный от ApiController, который возвращает данные по запросу. Мне нужно отправить несколько коллекций данных сразу, которые упакованы в классе WorkspaceData.

```
public class WorkspaceData
{
    public ObservableCollection<IDealing> DealingData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IDealingsStage> DealingsStage { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Client> ClientData { get; set; }
}
```

Мониторинг ответов веду через Fiddler. 
Сервер возвращает ошибку 500. Почему не передается отдельный объект? Хотя IEnumerable отлично приходит к кодом 200.

Comment: а ты дебажил этот метод?
может там эксепшон в логике

и какая инфа в ошибке?может там есть детали исключения?